# Python 3.Kivy. Is there any way to limit entered text in TextInput widget?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm writing kivy app and resently I faced with a  problem of unlimited inputing text in TextInput widget. Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Do you want the number of characters to have a maximum?

Comment: Yes that what I'm loking for

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A possible solution is to create a new property and overwrite the insert_text method:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty


class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    max_characters = NumericProperty(0)
    def insert_text(self, substring, from_undo=False):
        if len(self.text) > self.max_characters and self.max_characters > 0:
            substring = ""
        TextInput.insert_text(self, substring, from_undo)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyTextInput(max_characters=4)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do something like this, as well, and also needed to capitalize the text input for uniformity. Here is what I came up with..

First, I created a new class:

```
class CapitalInput(TextInput):
    max_length = 15 # sets max length of TextInput to 15 chars
```

Inside the class, I created a method:

```
def insert_text(self, substring, from_undo = False):
        s = substring.upper().strip()
        if len(self.text) <= self.max_length:
            return super(CapitalInput, self).insert_text(s, from_undo = from_undo)
```

Note: You don't need to keep ".upper()" inside the method if you don't need it. If you remove that part, it'll work just fine.

Lastly, inside your program, when you need to use this modified **TextInput**, simply use this:

```
self.whatever_your_user_input_is_called = CapitalInput(multiline = False, padding_y = (8, 4))
self.window.add_widget(self.whatever_your_user_input_is_called)
```

And that's it! Hopefully this solution helped you as it did me.

Answer (score 0):

(I can't comment so I am replying here)

Mova's answer is allowing one character over the limit. This is because the additional inserted character is not part of self.text until the end of the method.

```
class CapitalInput(TextInput):
    max_length = 15 # sets max length of TextInput to 15 chars
```

and the corrected method:

```
def insert_text(self, substring, from_undo = False):
        s = substring.upper().strip()
        if len(self.text)+1 <= self.max_length:
            return super(CapitalInput, self).insert_text(s, from_undo = from_undo)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35618089)

Comment: Hi Tyrone, I don't get what you mean. The entire code is there and it directly answers the question.